# How to concatenate all the cell values with each cell value as 'cell_value' and seperated by a comma

Tags: excel, excel-formula

i have a excel with the below column headers.How can i generate a new column which has each cell value from the below listed columns in a '' and seperated by a comma(,).This is required so that the data can be loaded into a Oracle table.

Column headers(A till K):
Configuration_Setting_ID,Configuration_Setting_Name,Description,Assessment_Procedure,Automated_Implementation,Default_Break_Severity,Default_Vulnerability,Technology_Hierarchy,Configuration_Setting_Owner,Status,Published_Date

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fC5eZ.png)

required format after combining all the values in a row:
'Configuration_Setting_ID','Configuration_Setting_Name','Description','Assessment_Procedure','Automated_Implementation','Default_Break_Severity','Default_Vulnerability','Technology_Hierarchy','Configuration_Setting_Owner','Status','Published_Date'

i tried to use the CONCAT function like =CONCAT('A','B','C',....'K') which didnt work

Comment: `=TEXTJOIN(",",,""""&<Your Headers>&"""")`

Comment: Sorry its not the headers i wanted to join..its the values in the columns

Comment: Then you can use `BYROW()` and change the '<Your Headers>' part to the entire body of your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your first header was in Cell `A1`, then your formula could be

```
='&TEXTJOIN("','",,$A2:$L2)&'
```

Assuming you wanted the inverted commas in your final product. If not, it would be:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",,$A2:$L2)
```